# HRESULT 0x80072EE4 when using BackgroundDownloader

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

Every time when I call CreateDownload on a BackgroundDownloader in my C# code for a Windows Store application, I get the following exception: `Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EE4`. I have declared all necessary capabilities in my package file.

**Example** This code breaks when CreateDownload() is called:

```
public static async void DownloadFile(string url){
    var uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);            
    FileSavePicker openPicker = new FileSavePicker();
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;            
    openPicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Video file", new List<string>() { ".mp4" }); 
    StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        DownloadOperation downloader = new BackgroundDownloader().CreateDownload(uri, file); //BREAKS HERE            
        //... (rest of code)
    }
}
```

**Exception** This is the exact exception I get:

```
System.Exception was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147012892
  Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EE4
  Source=Windows.Networking
  StackTrace:
   at Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundDownloader.CreateDownload(Uri uri, IStorageFile resultFile)
       at Example.BlankPage1.<DownloadFile>d__1.MoveNext()
  InnerException:
```

When I try to run the *[Windows 8.1 Background Transfer sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61)*, I get the same exception at the same method.

When Googling on `0x80072EE4`, it is suggested that moving Temporary Internet Files would solve the issue. In my case, it didn't work.

Comment: Anuthing in that InnerException?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: No, it is empty.

Comment: It is a Windows error code, 12004 = ERROR_INTERNET_INTERNAL_ERROR, "An internal error has occurred".  Well, that ought to narrow it down :(  That WinRT was designed by the Microsoft Windows group instead of DevDiv is painfully obvious in the error reporting.

Comment: Are you trying this in the simulator or an actual desktop?

Comment: @NateDiamond, my actual desktop. Simulator gives the same result, seems to use my desktop environment.

Comment: @Wietze Did you ever figure out the cause of this exception? I am starting to see it in error reports, but the HRESULT code is not really helping.

Comment: Eventually, the problem did no longer show up. Possibly as the result of an update of .NET Framework or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but still, I guess I just found some input for what it's worth.

I was getting the HRESULT: 0x80072EE4 error after removing all permissions for the windows user/account that (I guess) my app is using for writing temp files when using background-downloader (and probably other stuff).

Check the permissions on the "{userAccount}\AppData\Local\Packages{yourAppName}\AC" folder, and specifically the "BackgroundTransferApi" folder in there, and make sure that there is an account named something like "S-1-15-2-.......{veryLongString}" and that it has all the permissions set.

Hope this helps some future visitor :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I received this error with the SSL certificate was invalid on the site I was trying to access.

Specifically: NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

When I resolved the SSL certificate - the background downloader no longer had that error.