# UWP Background Transfer exception 0x80072EE4 after Windows Update 1703

Tags: exception, uwp, background-transfer, creators-update

I have a Windows Store app with [Background Transfer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer)  to download contents and it is working well until now. However, a few customers report that after they update their PC to Creators Update (1703), the downloads stop working giving an error like `HRESULT: 0x80072EE4` (which is translated from an exception by my app).

There are similar reports: [HRESULT 0x80072EE4 when using BackgroundDownloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364295/hresult-0x80072ee4-when-using-backgrounddownloader/35184835) but in my case, it happens after Windows Update 1703. Strangely, this issue doesn't happen on my developer PC where the same update is already installed.

Is there anyone has any clue on the source of the problem or found any workaround?

Comment: Is there any crash report in the dash board in DevCenter?

Comment: @Scavenger No, since it's not a crash: the exception is cached and processed by showing error to user.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the registry key pointing to the user's Temporary Internet Files cache is gone. If you look in Internet Explorer 11 under Internet Options -->General and click settings under browser history there will be nothing under "current location" and a disk space to use of zero. You may notice that Edge crashes immediately if you try to View Advanced Settings under Settings (at least it did in previous versions.)To reset it to the default I followed these instructions:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b433f6c6-a9fe-4ca6-aeba-ab9f0fc049a7/reset-temporary-internet-files-back-to-default-location?forum=w8itprogeneral

> Press windows key + R to get the Run dialog and enter regedit end
>   press ok.
>
> In the registry editor go to the following key:
>
> HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User
>   Shell Folders
>
> Double click the cache key and enter the initial location like this
>   including capitals:
>
> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
>
> Press ok to confirm and you will see the key changed.
>
> Then go to the following registry key:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User
>   Shell Folders
>
> Look at the cache key, it should be automatically changed to the
>   correct location as well, if not double click it and enter the correct
>   location end pres ok to confirm:
>
> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
>
> Reboot your pc, login and open Internet explorer and check the
>   location of Temporary internet files.